# Single Sign On with Kerberos in Eclipse RCP based application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, single-sign-on, kerberos, jaas

I currently developing multiple Eclipse RCP based application which manipulates same resource (database and files).
I want to provide Single Sign On feature to these applications so the user doesn't need to provide his/her credentials. I want you Kerberos as it is inbuilt in windows, so logged in window user can log in to my application too.

Any tutorial link or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks Shashwat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot didn't found any help regarding this question. So, used java based NTLM authentication.